# Django REST API fails tests when saving models, but runs fine

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing

I'm pretty lost on this. I have a ModelViewSet from Django's REST Framework that performs some custom functionality on POST requests by overriding the `perform_create` method. It looks like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset         = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserFlat

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
         serializer.save()

         try:
             profile_country = self.request.data['country']
             profile_phone = self.request.data['phone']

             profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=serializer.data['id'])
             country = Country.objects.get(country_code=profile_country)

             # both of these return the object just fine
             # print profile
             # print country

             # Take the profile object and set these attributes. It has a ForeignKey relation with the country
             profile.phone  = profile_phone
             profile.origin = country

             # This is where Django's TestCase fails
             profile.save()

         except:
             print "Attributes not provided"
```

So I tested the above in my terminal with `httpie` and it POSTS just fine. When I go to check the DB, every all the information is there. The User object was created and a new Profile object was created with the ForeignKey to the Country and phone number (I create the Profile object with a post_save signal)

When I run the tests though, it fails at the `profile.save()` section. I've confirmed that the Country object was created in the DB prior to the test and if I print it out while running the test I can see that it clearly picks up the all the relevant info.

`http POST :8000/api/v1/users/ username=test password=test last_name=test first_name=test email=test@test.com country=US phone=555`

The line above runs in my terminal posts successfully to my database

Here's the failing TestCase though

```
class APITestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    def test_create_user_profile_through_api(self):
    url = '/api/v1/users/'

    # country = Country.objects.get(country_code='US')

    data = {
        'first_name':'Tom',
        'last_name':'Sawyer',
        'username':'tomsawyer',
        'password':'tomsawyer',
        'email':'tomsawyer@tomsawyer.com',
        'country': 'US',
        'phone':'5555555555'
    }

    # The test fails to save the additional profile information profile.save() within
    # the view's perform_create method. Why is that?
    post = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')

    # request = self.client.get('/api/v1/users/3')
    # Profile.objects.get(id=3) 
    # both lines above are me checking to see if the profile object showed
    # up with the relevant country and phone number fields. Fields are 
    # are empty although the profile object is there

    # I didn't write the assertion yet as the line above keeps coming up empty
```

When I run my test, the except block of my view comes up `"Attributes not provided"`

EDIT:
On another note, I've checked things like authentication and even turned it off/forced it through the REST Framework and that's all fine. I'm able to successfully post and retrieve from the API and without the API for all other scenarios

EDIT: Traceback

```
  File "app/api/views.py", line 86, in perform_create
profile.save()

 File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
DataError: integer out of range
```

Comment: First get rid of that harmful `except` clause - all it does is preventing you from getting the relevant informations (exception type and message and full traceback) about what went wrong, then come back here post theses informations (but chances are you'll know enough by that time to solve the problem by yourself).

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this. The traceback shows line 86 (profile.save()) and says `DataError: Integer out of range`. I've updated above with the traceback

Comment: Do the matching Profile and Country instances exist when you run the test? As in do you load those as fixtures or by other means.

Comment: That's certainly not the *full* traceback - there are quite a few other stack frames between the call to `profile.save()` and django/db/backends/utils.py.

Also just out of curiousity: you didn't use a `models.IntegerField` to store the phone number, did you ?

Comment: haha sorry I'm new at this, I wasn't sure what all the other lines meant. Yes I did use `models.IntegerField`. I actually just commented it out and its working fine but I'm not sure why that stopped it. I tried using `int()` on the phone number and that didn't help. My model field is defined as `models.IntegerField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: Ok I found it. So setting the max_length on the IntegerField doesn't really help with large numbers apparently